# CodeMirror : Start and end line numbers of the rendered DOM

Tags: codemirror

As far as i know, codemirror renders only few lines into the DOM, if a file has lots of lines.  Is there any variable or function that could give me start and end line numbers in the rendered DOM?

For example, if i have 1000 lines in my file and if i am in mid of my file, code mirror might have rendered only lines from 400 to 500 into the DOM. How can i get those start and end line numbers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the line numbers range of the visible area by calling `cm.getViewport()`.

From the [docs](http://codemirror.net/doc/manual.html#getViewport):

> **`cm.getViewport()`** → `{from: number, to: number}`
>
> Returns a `{from, to}` object indicating the start (inclusive) and
>   end (exclusive) of the currently rendered part of the document. In big
>   documents, when most content is scrolled out of view, CodeMirror will
>   only render the visible part, and a margin around it. See also the
>   [viewportChange](http://codemirror.net/doc/manual.html#event_viewportChange) event.